# How to pass variable into the title of a scenario/scenario title in Karate framework

Tags: karate

While using data-driven feature in Karate framework, I see the generated report just show the title as configured in Scenario Outline NOT attached the value using in Example table. It causes the Tester confuse which data is using, and take time to expand each scenarios to know which data is using; so I want the report can pass variable into the title - Scenario/Scenario Outline. Please take a look at the example below.

E.g.

```
Feature: Login Feature


  Background:
    * configure headers = { 'Webapp-Version': '1.0.0'}

  Scenario Outline:   As a <description> user, I want to get the corresponding response_code <status_code>
      Given def path = 'classpath:features/Authentication/authentication.feature'
      And def signIn = call read(path) {username: '<username>', password: '1234567890'}
      Then match signIn.status == <status_code>


      Examples:
           |username       | status_code| description |
           |test@gmail.com | 200        | valid user  |
           |null           | 400        | invalid user|
```

My expected result, the generated report should fill the value on table for field "status code" and "description" fields.
->  As a valid user user, I want to get the corresponding response_code 200.

Please share your ideas and comments on it.

Thanks,

Learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported. Just use the `print` syntax and you will see it in the report.

EDIT: okay this will be possible in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/553